# How do i remove "\n" from an entry within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I've edited the original question as it was no longer relevant, so here is the new request:

I have a text file that contains this:

```
Sender,Date,Subject
SolarAlert <noreply@example.com>,2019-01-11,SolarAlert Alert: DATAALRT
SolarAlert <noreply@example.com>,2019-01-11,SolarAlert Alert: NETALRT
SolarAlert <noreply@example.com>,2019-01-11,SolarAlert Alert: SFOALRT
```

Using the following, i'm able to reference the text i require (DATAALRT, NETALRT, SFOALRT).

```
OPENDOC = open('Alert.txt', 'r')
READDOC = OPENDOC
for line in READDOC:
    rows = [line.split(': ', 2)[-1] for line in READDOC]
newrow = rows

print(rows)
print(rows[1])
```

But each row also includes a "\n". How would i remove that?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to iterate `for line in body:` and then never actually use the `line` variable. It's also unusual to call that variable "line", because you're iterating over every character in the file, not every line in the file.

Comment: Where do you use the variable `line` in your `for` loop and what Body contains?
For debugging try to print the different variables to see whether they are what you expect !

Comment: body is an entire string. `for line in body` does not give a line, it gives a character. each iteration of the loop you try to split the `body` aka entire string, so naturally you'll see what you see.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly do you want to write to each file? What would their contents be afterwards if it worked the way you want?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! @martineau I want to write the name of the line into a new file of the same name i.e. NETALRT.txt would contain NETALRT

Comment: What is "the name of the line"?

Comment: I think you want to look at `splitlines()`

Comment: The `timestr` is not doing what you want, as the program completes within one second, so it is repeatedly assigned the same value. It was a good debugging idea, but you wanted a counter (`i = 0` ... `i += 1`) rather than a time stamp.

Comment: Your sample input file contains 3 different things after "Alert:", which one do you want? If you don't  require any of the other data, what's supposed to be in the output file or file(s)? Please [edit] your question and show what result(s) you expect/want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that reads `'Alert.txt'` and create a variable named `rows` whose value is `['DATAALRT', 'NETALRT', 'SFOALRT']`:

```
rows = []
with open('Alert.txt', 'r') as READDOC:
    for line in READDOC.readlines():
        if ': ' in line:
            rows.append(line.strip().split(': ', 2)[-1])
print(rows)
```

> But each row also includes a "\n". How would i remove that?

To remove "\n" in the end of a string, just use `str.strip()`.